# How to run command when popup shows up?

Tags: prism

I need to execute a command when popup shows up, like `Loaded` event, how can I do that? Do I need to override `PopupWindowAction` or it's supported already?

Answer (score 0):

An interaction request is normally raised from code - execute the command just before raising the request, if that's possible.

Or you can execute it from the constructor of your popup's view model, that should happen a litte later.

As a last option, you can react to the `Loaded` event of your popup's content.
Another last option would be to override `PopupWindowAction.CreateWindow` and attach a handler to execute your command, but I'd prefer one of the code-only options that work without the actual view.

Comment: Hi, requirement is after popup showed, verification codes called and when invalid, it shows up confirmation to ask user if he want to continue, if confirmation returns false then close the popup. I don't want to call this verification in the code that raises the request. I tried to trigger it when Notification set but got this crash:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: This Visual is not connected to a PresentationSource.`

Can you explain you last paragraph?

Comment: This exception occurs when code raises nested popup while the main popup hasn't show yet.

Comment: So you want to trigger a popup from the popup? I guess, you could put an interaction trigger in the popup's content, but I wouldn't like that as a user. One popup at a time is enough, better show the result of the verification in the popup itself.